# How to hide LCJS ChartXY tick labels but display grid

Tags: lightningchart

.setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Empty);

please refer the pic.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "grid" is formed by the intersections of all Axis ticks.

If you want to hide the tick labels, but keep the grid, you can do it by hiding tick label style (text) and tick style (small tick between axis and label).

Please refer to the [official documentation Numeric Ticks FAQ](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.1/index.html#numeric-ticks) for tick style syntax.

In this case, `VisibleTicks.setTickStyle(emptyLine).setLabelFillStyle(emptyFill)` to hide these two parts.

Answer (score 0):

Took me like three days to figure this out. This is set to work on a chart that has a DateTime horizontal axis, but you could tweak a little to work for two number axii. All complaining aside about why this is the way you set things like axis tick visibility:

```
//turning axis labels off entirely:
function disableTicks(chartObj) {
    chartObj.getDefaultAxisX().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.DateTime,(ticks) =>ticks.setDateOrigin(dateOrigin).setMajorTickStyle((style)=>style.setTickStyle(emptyLine)
    .setLabelFillStyle(emptyFill)
    ).setMinorTickStyle((style)=>style.setTickStyle(emptyLine)
    .setLabelFillStyle(emptyFill)
    ))
    
    chartObj.getDefaultAxisY().setTickStrategy(AxisTickStrategies.Numeric,(ticks) =>ticks.setMajorTickStyle((style)=>style.setTickStyle(emptyLine)
    .setLabelFillStyle(emptyFill)
    ).setMinorTickStyle((style)=>style.setTickStyle(emptyLine)
    .setLabelFillStyle(emptyFill)
    )) 
}
```

You also need to add 'emptyFill' alongside the other declarations (or imports? I've been out of my depth for miles now) at top of your html like so:

```
<script src="/js/lcjs/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
<script>const { lightningChart,OHLCSeriesTypes, OHLCFigures,
    AxisTickStrategies,
    LegendBoxBuilders,
    Themes, SolidLine, SolidFill, PointShape, ColorHEX, emptyLine, emptyTick,emptyFill } = lcjs</script>
```